# Setting conditional background image from meta value

Tags: theme-development, settings-api

I am trying to set background image from meta value.I am successful also.But if the meta image is not set the out put

```
<div id="pricing" style="background: url('')"></div>
```

But I do not want to show `background: url('')` if there is not meta value is set.My code to get image

```
        $bgimage= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'settings_image', true );
        $img=background-image: url('.wp_get_attachment_url( $bgimage ).');
```

To display `style="<?php echo $img;?>"`
I have tried

```
    if(isset($bgimage)){
    $img=background-image: url('.wp_get_attachment_url( $bgimage ).');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try using an empty condition

```
<?php
$bgimage= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'settings_image', true );
if (!empty($bgimage)) {
    $imgURL = wp_get_attachment_url( $bgimage );
   ?>background: url('<?php echo $img ?>')<?php } ?>
```

That should work as it checks to see if there is anything stored in the meta and will not print the `background: url('')` if there is no data.